# Quickest formula method to create a list without duplicates

Tags: excel, list, duplicates

I have a list of entries using formula only i want to clean the duplicate values. What is the most efficient and quickest formula way to do that?

In rows i have number+text (few letters)

My column is something like:

```
AA3
AA6
AA25
AA45
```

I would prefer to extract it with use of one formula only

Comment: The answer would depend on whether the entries in question are numeric, text, or a mixture of both.

Comment: numeric+text all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming entries in `A1:A10`, first go to *Name Manager* (*Formulas* tab) and define:

*Name*: `Arry1`

*Refers to*: `=ROW($A$1:$A$10)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$10))+1`

then enter this **array formula****, used to count the expected number of returns, in `B1`:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A10,A1:A10,0),Arry1),1))`

Then enter this array **formula**** in `C1`:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>B$1,"",INDEX(A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$1:A$10,A$1:A$10,0),Arry1),Arry1),ROWS($1:1))))`

and copy down until you start to get blanks.

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*